# Always getting errors trying to import csv file into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, import

I am trying to import one csv file into a table of my database. 
The first two lines of the csv file are:

```
Nr$Name$Telefon$Flaeche$Einwohner$Pendler    
1$Innenstadt$069 755 10100$2.11$10100$
```

The table ("polizeireviere") in which I am trying to import to is like this:

```
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+     
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |     
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+      
| Nr        | int(5)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |      
| Name      | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |     
| Telefon   | varchar(34)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |    
| Flaeche   | decimal(10,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |     
| Einwohner | int(10)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |     
| Pendler   | int(10)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |     
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

My commands to import were these:

```
load data infile 'polizeireviere.csv'    
into table polizeireviere     
fields terminated by '$'    
lines terminated by '\n'    
ignore 1 lines;
```

But then I am getting this error:

```
' for column 'Pendler' at row 1nteger value: '
```

But I have no idea what that means, because all entries in the column 'Pendler' are all empty or integer numbers.

Comment: Maybe it's because you're not indicating a value for Pendler? Try using `NULL`:
Nr$Name$Telefon$Flaeche$Einwohner$Pendler
1$Innenstadt$069 755 10100$2.11$10100$NULL

Comment: Do you mean changing the csv file and writing in every empty spot "NULL" ? My task is it not to change anything in the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this issue using **SET** clause as below:

Your load command should look like:

```
load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/vivek/test.dat' 
into table polizeireviere
fields terminated by '$'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 rows
(Nr,Name,Telefon,Flaeche,Einwohner,@Pendler)
SET Pendler = IF(@Pendler='',null,@Pendler);
```

## Example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE polizeireviere (
    ->   Nr int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   Name varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   Telefon varchar(34) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   Flaeche decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   Einwohner int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   Pendler int(10) DEFAULT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.46 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/vivek/test.dat' 
    -> into table polizeireviere
    -> fields terminated by '$'
    -> lines terminated by '\n'
    -> ignore 1 rows
    -> (Nr,Name,Telefon,Flaeche,Einwohner,@Pendler)
    -> SET Pendler = IF(@Pendler='',null,@Pendler);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> select * from polizeireviere;
+------+------------+---------------+---------+-----------+---------+
| Nr   | Name       | Telefon       | Flaeche | Einwohner | Pendler |
+------+------------+---------------+---------+-----------+---------+
|    1 | Innenstadt | 069 755 10100 |       2 |     10100 |    NULL |
+------+------------+---------------+---------+-----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```